# Dynamic library does not appear when compiling with Debian but appears with Manjaro

Tags: node.js, compilation, linker, node.js-addon

I'm trying to create Node.js bindings for the Google's cld3 library. Node.js bindings are just a shared library that Node.js can use and map to Javascript code.

I have an error when running my Node.js program on anything else than Manjaro.

The error says that there is an undefined symbol:

```
$ docker run --rm -it node-cld3:node                               

> node-cld3@1.0.0 test
> node --test

 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1341
   return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                  ^
 
 Error: /build/build/Release/cld3.node: undefined symbol: _ZNK6google8protobuf11MessageLite25InitializationErrorStringEv
     at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1341:18)
     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:19)
     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
     at bindings (/build/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/build/index.cjs:4:33)
     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32) {
   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
 }
```

I found that the Node.js bindings list different dynamic libraries depending wether I compile with Manjaro or Debian. When compiling with Manjaro, the `libprotobuf-lite.so` is listed and I can run the program.

I am using CMake for the compilation, a reproducible example is available on Github https://github.com/Aschen/node-cld3

[image]

How is it possible to have the `libprotobuf-lite.so` listed on one case and not the other?

Comment: Just a small tip: I am currently working very actively on NAPI support for SWIG and I am using ImageMagick as showcase - you can see it at https://github.com/mmomtchev/node-magickwand
The NAPI support still hasn't been merged but it is definitely more than usable, I invite you to take a look at it since it can reduce your work by an order of magnitude

Comment: Your first step in identifying the problem should be `node-gyp build -v` - look to see if all the libraries are linked in - maybe there is a `pkg-config` step that doesn't work